# Is there md-checkbox multiple selection available in angular2 Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material2, multipleselection

Ive checked the documentation, but alas I have not been fortunate to reach to my desired destination.

I have a table of rows. In each row I have a `md-checkbox`, and I can select which is good. But I want to provide the functionality that that user should be able to select multiple checkboxes between the two selected checkboxes. From example, if I select the top checkbox, and I select the bottom checkbox, everything between them should be selected. This is very similar to gmail multiple selection.

[image]

Something like this.

Is this possible to do with `md-checkbox` in angular2?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for this, but you could do it yourself.

```js
  @ViewChildren(MdCheckbox) checkboxes;

  private _lastSelected;

  private cbClick(index: number, event: any) {
    if (this._lastSelected >= 0 && event.shiftKey) {
      let cbs = this.checkboxes.toArray();
      if (cbs[this._lastSelected].checked) {

        let firstIndex = index >= this._lastSelected ? this._lastSelected : index;
        let lastIndex = index >= this._lastSelected ? index : this._lastSelected;

        cbs.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1).forEach(c => c.checked = true);
      }
    }

    this._lastSelected = index;
  }
```

```html
  <div *ngFor="let o of options; let idx = index">
    <br />
    <md-checkbox (click)="cbClick(idx, $event)">{{ o }}</md-checkbox>
  </div>
```

See my working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IiBJpv18zv656ZrTFxAn?p=preview